# Linux terminal connecting to 127.0.0.1 port 8888 on HTTP calls

Tags: apache, http, ubuntu-14.04

I am using ubuntu 14.04 with LAMP stack working and listening on port 80.
I don't exactly remember what went wrong, now that I make any http request from the terminal it try's to connect to 127.0.0.1 on port 8888(port 8888 does not exist). Any guidance on fixing this issue will be appreciated.

```
wget http //nmap.org/dist/nmap-5.51.tar.bz2
--2017-06-13 15:20:11--  http://http/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8888... failed: Connection refused.
//nmap.org/dist/nmap-5.51.tar.bz2: Scheme missing.

git pull
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/SwipBox/admin.git/': Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8888: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command

```
wget http //nmap.org/dist/nmap-5.51.tar.bz2
```

Needs to be:

```
wget http://nmap.org/dist/nmap-5.51.tar.bz2
```

Also, make sure you don't have any environment variables such as `http_proxy` defined.  If in doubt, pass `--no-proxy` to the command line of wget.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I checked with { printenv http_proxy } command i see the proxy is set to 127.0.0.1:8888, how do i unset this and to what value should i keep this environment variable to so it wont interfere with my applications?

Comment: From Ubuntu System Settings, click Network icon and then inspect the Network Proxy setting.  Otherwise, inspect `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc`, or any config file in `/etc`.